# How to call redux action from static navigationOptions?

Tags: react-native

I need to call a action from static navigationOptions but cannot access my action through this.props. How to call this action? I am getting error "Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined" in console.

```js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) =>( {
        title: 'Home',
        header: <Header headerTitle={navigation.state.routeName} logoutButtonPress={() => {
        this.props.logout(); // this action is not working 
                NavigationActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Welcome" })]
                })
                navigation.navigate('Welcome');
            }
            }
        />,
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

In component of screen where there is navigationOptions

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      logOut: this.actionLogOut
    });
  }

actionLogOut = () => {
this.props.dispatch(logOut()); };
```

Load function action of logout in params of navigation when componentDidMount and then

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  headerTitle: (
    <Text
      style={{
        left: Platform.OS == "android" ? 20 : 0
      }}
    >
      Personal Data
    </Text>
  ),
  headerRight: (
    <Aux>
      <Icon
        name="md-notifications"
        size={27}
        color="#9D9B9C"
        style={{ paddingLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}
      />
      <Icon
        name="ios-log-out"
        size={27}
        color="red"
        style={{ paddingLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(navigation);
          navigation.state.params.logOut();
          navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({ index: "Login" }));
          navigation.popToTop();
        }}
      />
    </Aux>
  )
};
```

};

In navigationOptions use as navigation.state.params.logOut();

This component must use connect using import { connect } from "react-redux" and connect with component

Comment: Way to go, this helped me so much as an example. I made a slightly different approach and had to use `navigation.getParam('logOut')` instead, but this was a pretty good example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the `logout` button as a `component` and bind the `props` explicitly from the `react-redux` module `mapDispatchToProps`

For example

```
   const LogoutButton = ({logout}) => {
     return (
      <TouchableOpacity  style={{height: 50, width: 100}} onPress={() => logout()}>
        <Text>Logout</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
     )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  logout: () => /*dispatch your logout action here*/
})
```

and use it in your **`static navigationOptions`** as

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) =>( {
        title: 'Home',
        header: <Header headerTitle={navigation.state.routeName}
        /><Logout/>,
      });
```

or modify your  component to support this component.

Comment: Getting error "undefined". It is unable to identify argument "logout" in component logoutButton

Comment: Is your `parent component` connected to `redux` store like this - `export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponentName)`

Comment: If parent means Current screen in which navigationOptions is using then yes it is connected